# Getting the original symbol name when writing a macro

Tags: macros, clojure, lisp

I have written the following macro, that defines records with a custom string representation.

```
(defmacro defrecord*
  [rname args]
  `(defrecord ~rname [~@args]
     Object
     (toString [_]
       ~(let [kvs (->> args
                       (map (fn [arg] [(str arg ": ") arg]))
                       (interpose ", ")
                       (apply concat))]
          `(str ~rname "(" ~@kvs ")")))))
```

However what `toString` returns is not quite what I am expecting.

```
(defrecord* Foo [bar baz]) 
(.toString (Foo. 3 4))

> "class user.Foo(bar: 3, baz: 4)"
```

I'd like my `toString` to return `Foo(bar: 3, baz: 4)` in this case. What change do I need to make to get a string representation in this format?

Also what changes, if any, should I make to the above code to make it more idiomatic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `~rname` with `'~rname` - you want the actual symbol `Foo`, not its value in the current scope, which is the class `user.Foo`.

You also have `(apply concat)` and `(interpose ", ")` in the wrong order - you'll be treating `", "` as a sequence, and adding `\,` and `\space` characters instead of a single string. Once you swap that, it becomes clear that you want `mapcat` instead of `(apply concat (map ...))`. So I'd replace your whole let-block with something like:

```
`(str '~rname
      "(" ~@(interpose ", "
                       (mapcat (fn [arg] [(str arg ": ") arg])
                               args))
      ")")
```

Or if you really want to grind out that performance, you can compute `~(str "(" rname)` at compile-time instead of at runtime.

Please note, though, that as of Clojure 1.3 records already print in a way very similar to this, so if you're just doing this to make debugging easy, don't bother. If you're doing it because you're using `.toString`'s output later on down the line...well, shame on whoever wrote that code, as `.toString` is mostly for debugging stuff.

Comment: I'm doing this only because I am learning macros. :) Thanks. I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just change `~rname` to `~(name rname)`:

```
(defmacro defrecord*
  [rname args]
  `(defrecord ~rname [~@args]
     Object
     (toString [_]
       ~(let [kvs (->> args
                       (map (fn [arg] [(str arg ": ") arg]))
                       (interpose ", ")
                       (apply concat))]
          `(str ~(name rname) "(" ~@kvs ")")))))
```

Comment: No problem. As far as idiomaticity goes, I don't think there's much to add to amalloy's answer.